# I always get errors in linker with Visual Studio 2019 and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2019

I installed OpenCV-v2.4.11 from NuGet Package Manager in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. However, I can't get working this code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat A;
    return 0;
}
```

I got these errors:
[image: Errors]

Errors once more: (Visualisation is name of my project)

```
 - Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ)  Visualisation   C:\Users\maoap\source\repos\Visualisation\Visualisation\Source.obj  1   
 - Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ)   Visualisation   C:\Users\maoap\source\repos\Visualisation\Visualisation\Source.obj  1   
 - Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPEAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ)   Visualisation   C:\Users\maoap\source\repos\Visualisation\Visualisation\Source.obj  1       
 - Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 3 unresolved externals  Visualisation   C:\Users\maoap\source\repos\Visualisation\x64\Debug\Visualisation.exe   1
```

Comment: So what have you done in visual studio to try and link with the opencv libraries?

Comment: Have you taken any of the steps [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) for instance?

Comment: I tried this tutorial first before installing from NuGet, however I couldn't complete it because of different MVS version - I don't have for example those options about Linker in Project Properties

Comment: Well you need those options. AFAIK the way you set linker options hasn't changed for a long time in Visial Studio.

Comment: Well I finally managed to get Linker settings highlighted and I went throught the tutorial you mentioned. Still have the same errors

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: New project configured totally the same (checked it many times) and it works, althought the second one not. I really don't understand that.

Comment: Visual Studio can show you the linker command line. Right click the project and pick properties. Then navigate to Configuration Properties/Linker/Command Line. Compare the command lines of the project that works and the one that doesn't, there must be a difference somewhere.

Comment: This advice about the linker command line is priceless, I needed exactly this kind of information. This solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) wrote in [a comment below the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234001/i-always-get-errors-in-linker-with-visual-studio-2019-and-opencv/57243808#comment100979408_57234001):

> Visual Studio can show you the linker command line. Right click the project and pick properties. Then navigate to Configuration Properties/Linker/Command Line. Compare the command lines of the project that works and the one that doesn't, there must be a difference somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler toolkits in vs 2019 are not compatible with opencv in Nuget or else now,there are two way you can choose:

1.compile opencv by yourself,you need to rewrite makefile.

2.use it in vs2015.